# InvalidCastException - passing null values to stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

i've not that much experience in programming, so I've no idea what is my fault.
I'm working on a dynamic search for a website, where you can search for different values.

This is my procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Support_for_Search]
@ID int, 
@Benutzername nvarchar(100),
@DatumEingang date, 
@Eskalation date,
@Prio tinyint,
@namePrefix nvarchar(100)

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT S.[ID]
  ,S.[Problembeschreibung]
  ,S.[Wunschtermin]
  ,S.[Projektkostenstelle]
  ,S.[Status]
  ,S.[BearbeiterID]
  ,S.[DatumEingang]
  ,S.[DatumAbschluss]
  ,S.[Priorität]
  ,S.[Eskalation]
  ,S.[Nutzerreaktion]
  ,S.[AntragstellerID]
  ,S.[Pcname]
  ,S.[Benutzername]
  ,S.[Bemerkungen] 
  ,B.Vorname + ' ' + B.Nachname AS AntragstellerName
  ,BA.Vorname + ' ' + BA.Nachname AS BearbeiterName
FROM [dbiSupportsystem].[dbo].[Support] S 
Left JOIN dbo.Benutzer B ON B.BenutzerNr = S.AntragstellerID
Left JOIN dbo.Benutzer BA ON BA.BenutzerNr = S.BearbeiterID
Where (@ID IS NULL OR ID = @ID)
AND 
(@Benutzername IS NULL OR Benutzername LIKE '%' + @Benutzername + '%')
AND
(@DatumEingang IS NULL OR DatumEingang = @DatumEingang)
AND 
(@Eskalation IS NULL OR Eskalation = @Eskalation)
AND
(@Prio IS NULL OR Priorität = @Prio)
AND 
(@namePrefix IS NULL OR B.Nachname LIKE '%' + @namePrefix + '%') 
END
```

The user could search for everything or nothing, so it should be possible to pass null values. When I test the procedure in the sql management studio, it works fine even when i pass only null values.

The results will be bind to a GridView.
Here is my could behind:

```
using (DataClassesDataContext context = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            SearchDG.DataSource = context.Support_for_Search(null, null,null, null,null, null);  
            SearchDG.DataBind(); 
        }
```

I'm passing the null values only for debugging, but i get an InvalidCastException on DataBind.

Some help would be very great.

I hope you understand everything, my english isn't that good.

Justin

Edit:

I've tested another way:

```
Int32? supportnummer;
        int parseSupportnummer;

        bool supportnummerIsInt = Int32.TryParse(txtSnummer.Text, out parseSupportnummer);
        if (supportnummerIsInt)
        { supportnummer = parseSupportnummer; }
        else
        { supportnummer = null; }  

DateTime? datumEingang;
DateTime parseEingang; 

        bool eingangIsDate = DateTime.TryParse(txtDatumEingang.Value, out parseEingang);
        if (eingangIsDate)
            { datumEingang = parseEingang; }
        else 
            { datumEingang = null; }
```

I've made a nullable variable for every parameter that i want to pass. 
I check if the textbox is empty. If it is then i assign null to the variable.

At the end I'm calling the procedure with these parameters:

```
SearchDG.DataSource = context.Support_for_Search(supportnummer, benutzername, datumEingang, datumEskalation, prio, userNachname);
```

But I have gotten the same InvalidCastException.

I did not mention it , that the post not get too complicated.

Comment: Are datumEskalation & prio also nullable?

Comment: Yes they are, and userNachname and benutzername also.

Comment: What's the signature of the stored procedure in C# code?

Comment: I'm not completley shure what you mean, but the procedure dont have a signature.

Comment: Signature is: parameters + types.

Comment: the signature is: "int?, string, DateTime?, DateTime?, byte?, string"

Comment: one more idea what could ne wrong?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **InvalidCastException** occurs when an explicit cast is applied. But the type is not in the same path of the type hierarchy. The cast does not succeed.

In your code you are passing everything as null. But **int**, **tinyint** and **date** cannot be null. That is why it is throwing exception

Alternatively you can make your variables **nullable** in c# code by adding a ? like this:
`int? variableName`

Check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx) link for more details on how to make variables nullable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried it with nullable variables before but i'm still getting the same expetion. Please look at my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing DBNull.Value instead of null

```
SearchDG.DataSource = context.Support_for_Search(DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: Suggestions to try something don't qualify as an answer. This should be a comment.

Comment: I need 24 more reputations for making comment.

Comment: So now you can turn it into a comment.